# Alter code to be simple in Net::OpenSSH

Tags: regex, perl, server

I am newbie in Perl programming and currently trying to use Net::OpenSSH module in my code, my new code as below which the task is to run multiple command in remote server,

Code as below::

```
---
---
foreach $s (@servers) {
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new("$username\@$s", timeout=>30);
$ssh->error and die "Unable to connect: " . $ssh->error;
print "Connected to $s\n";

my $fh = $ssh->capture("df -k /home/ | tail -1") or die "Unable to run command\n";
my @df_arr = split(/\s+/, $fh);
print "$s:  Disk space /home/ = $df_arr[3] \n";

my $fh1 = $ssh->capture("svmon -G -O unit=GB | grep memory") or die "Unable to run command\n";
my @sv_arr = split(/\s+/, $fh1);
print "$s:  Free memory = $sv_arr[3] \n\n";

close $fh;
undef $ssh;
}
----
----
```

This code is not so nice since I plan to make it more simplify and reduce a line as many as possible.

Does there are any technique's or methods that I can use to simplify this code?

Comment: For questions about beautifying working code, go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com .

Comment: You can start by indenting your code properly

Comment: You can try running everything in parallel using [Net::OpenSSH::Parallel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH::Parallel).

Answer (score 0):

our way to make it happen in this way:

1. sub ssh_connect($username, $password)
   $ssh = ssh_connect($username, $password)
2. sub ssh_execute($ssh, $command_str)

there are too much duplicated code in your origin code, maybe you can put them into a subroutine and reuse it.